# Aggrid groupIncludeFooter not working with RowModelType of serverSide

Tags: ag-grid

If rowmodeltype is client side which is default its working fine, Demo :
https://plnkr.co/edit/en9fRQKx5YnPxFEq

if rowmodeltype is Server side the groupIncludeFooter and groupIncludeTotalFooter is not working : Demo Link
https://plnkr.co/edit/3sZUX4tniRwRHN1r

```
[rowModelType]="rowModelType"
....
this.rowModelType = 'serverSide';
```

How to enable the [groupIncludeFooter]="true"
[groupIncludeTotalFooter]="true"
property when rowmodeltype is serverside ?